# How to apply the same fix to two separate branches with git

Tags: git

This is a question about a particular situation I have found when working with git.

Say I have an application with a master branch (several commits of course). The application is working.

Then I decide to (for example- the actual thing is not that important) translate the comments in the code so I create a branch called *translation* and I start to translate everything. I commit several times.

Then I realize there is a bug (**unrelated**　with translation). I can of course fix the bug but how is the correct way to proceed *with git*?

(take into account that this fix has to go to both the master version and the translated version, but the master does not have to have anything translated (so no merging I guess??)

I can think of two(2) possibilities:

1) go to master, create a fix branch, fix the bug and commit. Then go to translation and.... ooops... I don't know how to "copy" that fix there too

2) Correct in translation and merge?? (but then again, I can't merge the translation part??)

Comment: Ideally, you can fix the branch, then merge into the master.  Otherwise, I've always dealt with this situation simply by checking out master and the branch(es) separately, manually copying/pasting the fix into both, one at a time.

Comment: @paulsm4 I suppose I could do that but that seems error-prone and defeats the use of git I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1) is an hotfix strategy. You commit your patch in master and then cherry-pick that commit wherever you want/need.

The 2) is clearly not git oriented and error-prone

There is an existing 3) alternative. You can inject your fix into translation's history. How ? Your translation is based on master, right ? so you can commit on master and then rebase your translation branch on top of master. It will be like the fix was already included when you branched translation. Drawback : this will rewrite translation's history, so it's better if tranlation is a local branch. If it's not, you will have to force push your branch, which is far from ideal (if you don't know exactly what you are doing). *EDIT* Drawback 2 : In addition to that, 3) implies to include maybe other commits that you have inserted in the master branch history before your fix (which could be unwanted in the translation branch).

Comment: Thanks. So basically it is a) cherry-pick b) rebase. I will try them both with a simpler example and see which works more easily

Comment: The easiest way (and the most related to your use case) is clearly the hotfix strategy. You fix on master the bugs, so branches can, if needed, include the bugfix (because they have active need of it) or wait the merge to handle the diffs (because they dont care about the bugfix). It's a good strategy when a lot of people are working on the same project. Furthermore, as said in my answer, 3) can be problematic if you already pushed your translation branch.

Comment: In addition to that, 3) implies to include maybe other commit that you have done in the master branch history (which could be unwanted in the translation branch). I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend your first suggestion, namely just going back to `master` and fixing the bug there.  This assumes that the bug has nothing to do with translation of comments, which it probably does not.

Then, you may `rebase` your translation branch on `master`, to bring in the bug fix, before you get ready to merge this feature branch back to `master`.  You could get lots of merge conflicts because all the translations changed.  But, in that case, you might also get the same conflicts even if you were to completely ignore the bug fix.

Comment: So, I fix the bug in master, and then I rebase the whole translation to this new point? In that case, will the fix be applied to translation as well?

Comment: Yes, the rebase would bring in the fix commit from `master`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is like 1)

go to master, create a fix branch, fix the bug and commit. Then merte it into master, and merge master into *translation* branch

If you need only that fix for *translation* branch, you can `cherry-pick` the commit(s) into your branch.

Comment: If I merge master to translation then master is becoming translation, isn't it? that would be undesirable since master needs to stay in the original language (not translated)

Comment: Without merging master with translation, can I apply the same bug-fix to both master and translation?

Comment: Even if you merge master into translation, master won't change. master will stay in original. If you merge translation into master, master will change.

Comment: What you need is merging master into translation. So it would work nicely

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

1. Check out the commit that introduced the bug, however far back that is

   ```
   git checkout -b fixthatbug $thatcommit
   ```
2. fix the bug and commit it
3. merge the bugfix wherever it needs merging